# Wordpress error: (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) wp-db.php on line 1538

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this error message when I try to access wp-admin of my wordpress site:

[image: Error message]

I have set up a local server with Wampserver and it worked fine in the beginning, but now this error message appears whenever i try to go to: localhost/wordpress/wp-admin.

I have tried to change the password and it didn't help. I have also looked up line 1538 in wp-db.php as the error message suggests but I can't see the problem. It looks like this:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
} else {
    @mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
}
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: If you've changed the MySQL `root` user password, don't forget to execute [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-changes.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with line 1538 in wp-db.php. 
This line of code is just trying to establish a connection using the credentials that you supplied. 
The error is likely with the password provided in your wp-config.php file.

Try to log on to your MySQL server directly using the credentials that you have supplied in the wp-config.php file and see that they work correctly.

You should be able to connect to to your MySQL instance locally with your "MySQL Command Line Client" in Windows in order to test your password.

Comment: I have just tried that and it works fine. I can log in to my MySQL server using the MySQL console with my new password, but I still get the error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Another possible problem is that the host may be incorrect or have somehow changed. If you have phpmyadmin you can check the host in the mysql.user.
Otherwise you can run the following 2 commands in the MySQL command line:
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='localhost' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
This will set the root user have the correct permissions based on the error. Depending on your security you can also open up the permissions for root to connect from anywhere:
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='%' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Be aware that this may be a security risk

Comment: No that didn't help either. I have changed my MySQL port from 3306 to 3307, because port 3306 was occupied (probably by Skype) but when I go to my localhost it still says that the port defined for MySQL is 3306. Could that be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: OK, you could be running 2 MySQL servers?
Some possible fixes:
After making changes to Mysql config, don't forget to restart the MySQL serice to have changes take effect.
In order to use a different port for Wordpress database, change the following in wp-config.php:   
    define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307' );

Comment: Thank you! It worked after I changed ('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); to ('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307'); and restarted the services.

Comment: Great. for future reference, the information on the MySQL port change should have been included in the question to enable faster assistance. There are so many possible problem areas that the more information you provide, the better.

Answer (score 5):

For mysql-server-5.7 (I believe older versions didn't have this problem)
From my experience so far, and to start from scratch:

Let's start off with a clean slate:

```
cd /var/www/html/
wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz 
tar -xvzf latest.tar.gz
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress
```

This will download, extract, and fix any file permission / ownership issues.

Now we have to fix mysql_native_password issues

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

you will see a table as such:

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             |                                           | auth_socket           | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *CC744277A401A7D25BE1CA89AFF17BF607F876FF | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

then run:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Where 'password' is your root password that you set.

After doing this, run:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

You should see your root password inside.

This will fix the issue.

Also, you will run into the same exact issue with phpMyAdmin, so the same concepts with "mysql_native_password" and ALTERING your user, and file/folder ownership as we did above will fix these issues.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: edit w-p.config.php, replacing

```
define ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

with

```
define ('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the wp-config.php file and see how MySQL user and passwords are set.

```php
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxx');
```

Comment: These credentials are used to enter the database. Instead to edit the content of the site, open the home, scroll down the page to the bottom. you will find the links Login . Use the credentials set during the installation (user) to enter the Admin panel.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by letting wordpress handle the issue. Just do nothing on wp-config-sample and continue wordpress installation. Then wordpress will automatically create wp-config asking db name, user and password.